# 302 redirect to cart from successAction - why?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am running a **1.9.3.7** shop with a custom checkout [extension](https://amasty.com/single-step-checkout.html)  and whenever I try to make a purchase I am redirected to the cart. A also debugged this and was able to track it down to `successAction()` in `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`.

```
$session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    return;
}
```

When I use the standard checkout, it works ok. So it must be some sort of error in that extension. Anyone any idea where to sart looking?

Thanks!

Comment: @Amie you can error mode start and check console error